# Replace the first and last concurrence of characters only if the line starts with a specific word

Tags: regex, linux, unix, sed

If a line starts with "#", looking to replace the first occurrence of "(" and the last occurrence of ")" with whitespace as following:

Sample input: cat world.txt

```
MAP MT.POS(AUS) , SOUTH
#TARGET(MT.POS(USA) , NORTH)
MAP MT.POS(CAN) , NORTH
```

I am trying to do using sed as following

```
cat world.txt | sed -e '/^#/s/\(.*\))/\1 /; /^#/s/\(.*\)(/\1/'
```

Below is what I am expecting.

```
MAP MT.POS(AUS) , SOUTH
#TARGET MT.POS(USA) , NORTH
MAP MT.POS(CAN) , NORTH
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following `sed` command:

```
sed '/^#/s/(\(.*\))/\1/' file
```

`/^#/` is an address and matches lines starting with a `#`. Those lines are subject of the following `s` (*substitute*) command. It search for the first and the last parenthesis in the line and replaces them with the text between them.

Note that `.*` matches *greedy*. Meaning it will consume as much characters as possible (including parentheses) until the last closing parenthesis is found in the line.

Comment: Thank you.! I am thinking to do more like this sed '/^#/s/(\(.*\))/\t\1\t'